# How do I calculate the required heading for an aircraft carrier with an angled deck to sail into the wind?

Tags: landing, wind, aircraft-carrier

The natural wind is from 360 degrees at 10 knots. The desired relative wind down the angled deck is 10 degrees left of the ship’s heading at 30 knots.

What heading and speed must the carrier go?

Comment: Is it not 10 degrees and 20 knots?

Comment: Ha! Yeah, I think you’re right. Thet’d give you a bit less than 30 kts, but pretty durn close.  I was making it waaay too hard.  Thanks.

Comment: As I think about this further, I see it’s not right.  Heading the ship 10 right of the natual wind would put wind down the angle only when the ship was stopped. As the ship speed increases the relative wind direction will move closer and closer to the ship’s heading.

Comment: If the ship has to steam forward to make its own wind, it will never be right down the angled deck.  Just the limitations of the layout.

Comment: Where are we going to find a carrier to test the answer? :)

Comment: @Juan Jimenez, I wish I could just walk up to the bridge to ask them how they do it!  But, I imagine it isn't too complicated...

Comment: @Tad Chamberlain, just to clarify, you are absolutely correct in your statement that "as the ship speed increases the relative wind direction will move closer and closer to the ship’s heading."  However, the answer I gave below is also true.  This is the trade-off...

Comment: Just for curiousity's sake, why do you want to calculate it?  Rather than say point the ship more or less into the wind, then look at the wind sock and make corrections?  (Which you might have to do anyway, as winds change...)

Answer (score 3):

A carrier heading of 010 degrees at a speed of 20 knots would give you an acceptable solution.  You could perform some vector addition to compute the resultant wind and perhaps optimize this somewhat, but in reality the winds are generally not constant enough to make minor adjustments worth chasing.

Even if the winds were calm and the ship was making all 30 knots the crosswind component is almost negligible, and well within limits for any carrier based aircraft.  This happens a lot.  There is a bigger negative effect from  turbulence caused by the island structure when the ship has to make wind than any effect of increased crosswind.

Answer (score -1):

Let’s suppose that the runway is angled by 10º to the left. To start with, let’s assume there is no wind, and that we wish 30 kts of relative wind parallel to the runway. The speed of the carrier (with any heading) will be 30 kts/cos 10º = 30,46 kts.

Now, we have a wind with a speed of 10 knots in relation to the sea. We change the heading of the carrier in order to take the maximum advantage of that wind, so that it may be parallel to the runway. So the carrier steers to a heading exactly 10º to the right of the wind direction. Now we have too much wind, 30 + 10 = 40 kts, and we should reduce the ship’s speed in proportion to that excess of 40/30. In other words, the carrier should steam at 30,46 x 30/40 = 22,85 kts.

Hence, the carrier should have a heading of 10º to the right of the north, and a speed of 22,85 kts...

Comment: The conditions given in the original question was 10 knots of natural wind from due north.

Comment: True. Edited...